How can I insert a proper macron-A letter (ā) using pdftex?
MWE:
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
    Navā
\end{document}

This gets printed correctly, but when I select the text and attempt to copy it, it reveals two separate glyphs:


Nav¯a

How can I ensure that the macron letter is encoded as a true Unicode character in the PDF?
I have tried \usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}, \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}, \usepackage{lmodern}, and \usepackage{cmap}. I have also used \=a instead of ā with no success.

You need to use a font that supports this letter directly. If you compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTex, Latin Modern which supports this glyph will be used. If you compiile with PDFLaTex, Computer Modern will be used, where the glyph is generated automatically.

T1 encoding does not support that, so as Jasper wrote, you will have to use an unicode engine like lualatex.

It seems to be viewer-dependent, with Evince in Linux and compilation with pdfLaTeX the viewer correctly manages to copy ā with the regular input method. However, you might try Nav\BeginAccSupp{method=hex,unicode,ActualText=0101}ā\EndAccSupp{} using the accsupp package for more robust results.

all the above are correct. the T1 encoding doesn't use the pre-composed glyph, even if it is in the font, so the PDF cannot include the correct character. however, the copy-paste problem is viewer-dependent in that case because viewers such as Okular will still manage to paste the intended character. (whether this is the correct behaviour or not I don't know.)

@Marijn in my experience accsupp is also heavily viewer dependent.

Thanks everybody. I am using pdf.js (part of Mozilla, Overleaf, and Latex Workshop for VS Code) and accsupp seems not to work there. So apparently I will need to undertake a migration to xelatex or lualatex. It's unfortunate that many environments and templates still recommend using pdflatex despite its limitations.

@ChristophThiede lualatex is preferable, if you have a choice. pdftex still has some advantages, partly because publishers often won't accept submissions which require unicode engines and partly because it is significantly faster. so it would probably be better to explain the pros and cons of each choice, but the attraction of templates is that such choices are made for you :-). also, if most fonts don't have the characters you need, a unicode engine has fewer advantages.

Reported this issue to the pdf.js viewer repository: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/18832

The T1 encoding was devised to support a vast majority of European languages that use the Latin alphabet.
Latvian uses ā (and also ē, ī and ū), but these glyphs couldn't be inserted in the 256 available slots. Thus, under the T1 encoding the character is made up and copy-paste is not guaranteed to work, depending on the PDF viewer.
There exists the L7x encoding in the lithuanian bundle that supports it, but there are just a few fonts encoded that way. Happily, Latin Modern is among them.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Navā

\end{document}


The ā glyph is precomposed and copies correctly.
Here's the full character set.

All the TeX Gyre fonts support this encoding and also some others:
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cyklop/l7xcyklop.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gentium-tug/l7xgentium.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gentium-tug/l7xgentiumbook.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/iwona/l7xiwona.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/iwona/l7xiwonac.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/iwona/l7xiwonal.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/iwona/l7xiwonalc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/l7xkurier.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/l7xkurierc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/l7xkurierl.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kurier/l7xkurierlc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lithuanian/l7xuag.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lithuanian/l7xubk.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lithuanian/l7xucr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lithuanian/l7xuhv.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lithuanian/l7xunc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lithuanian/l7xupl.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lithuanian/l7xutm.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lithuanian/l7xuzc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/l7xlmdh.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/l7xlmr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/l7xlmss.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/l7xlmssq.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/l7xlmtt.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/l7xlmvtt.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mlmodern/l7xmlmdh.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mlmodern/l7xmlmr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mlmodern/l7xmlmss.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mlmodern/l7xmlmssq.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mlmodern/l7xmlmtt.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mlmodern/l7xmlmvtt.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/poltawski/l7xantp.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/poltawski/l7xantpl.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/l7xqag.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/l7xqbk.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/l7xqcr.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/l7xqcs.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/l7xqhv.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/l7xqhvc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/l7xqpl.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/l7xqtm.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tex-gyre/l7xqzc.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zlmtt/l7xzlmtt.fd
/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/zlmtt/l7xzlmvtt.fd

Switching to a Unicode engine (LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX) is best.
Added from comments
If your base font should be Palatino, you can use TeX Gyre Pagella, which is a clone thereof. In the list of the .fd file above it's l7xqpl.fd and is loaded with the tgpagella package.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage[L7x]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

Navā \textsc{Navā} \textit{Navā}

\end{document}



at least fonts often have these characters. if you need accented characters which are missing in most fonts, you're out of luck regardless of the engine and encoding you choose :(.

Thank you! By the way, I had to install l7xenc.def via sudo apt install texlive-lang-european. Unfortunately, my template uses Palatino, and when I add the L7x encoding, the ā is rendered correctly, but at the same time, all instances of \textsc are broken. Is that a limitation of the encoding (and lualatex will fix it) or the font?

@ChristophThiede You can use tgpagella which is a clone of Palatino. I added an example.

@egreg Thank you again. Is tgpagella really considered a drop-in-replacement for Palatino? My template uses \usepackage[largesc,p,osf]{newpxtext} and \usepackage{newpxmath}, and with tgpagella, I seem to lose at least the global old-style numbers. It also seems as iff I use the L7x encoding with tgpagella, the kerning of \textsc is reduced everywhere. Is it possible to avoid all these changes, or would I not have any of these problems by migrating to XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX?
